# How to display object attributes based on user choice?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am new to java object oriented programming and need help with a problem!

I created a variety of DVD objects and want to let the user choose an option, then display several attributes of the chosen DVD. However, I don't want to have to create 8 different cases for all the possible movie options. Is there a way to call on a method with a variable that corresponds to each DVD ID (which is the first variable I assigned)?

I tried creating an array list but it gives me an error

Any help is much appreciated!

```
    List<DVD> list = new ArrayList<DVD>(){
    DVD dvd1 = new DVD(1, "Movie 1");
    DVD dvd2 = new DVD(2, "Movie 2");
    DVD dvd3 = new DVD(3, "Movie 3");
    DVD dvd4 = new DVD(4, "Movie 4");
    DVD dvd5 = new DVD(5, "Movie 5");
    DVD dvd6 = new DVD(6, "Movie 6");
    DVD dvd7 = new DVD(7, "Movie 7");


        System.out.println("Enter your movie choice"); 
        int movieChoice = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println(list.get(movieChoice).getDVDName());
```

Comment: You have `javascript` as one of your tags. Change that to `java`

Comment: What error do you get? Also, you have a `{` at the and of the line where you initialize the list. Additionally, you never add any of your DVDs to the list (`list.add(dvd1)`).

Answer (score 0):

Use reflections to look for fields by names. Let's say `wanted` hash set contains names of fields needed to be processed.

```
Set<String> wanted = new HashSet<>();
    Stream.of(DVD.class.getDeclaredFields()).filter(field -> wanted.contains(field.getName())).forEach(field ->
            {
                boolean accesBuffer = field.isAccessible();
                field.setAccessible(true);
                //Do Something With the Field - get value, store in HashMap, etc.
                field.setAccessible(accesBuffer);
            }
    );
```